# Use of Git and its commands

Tags: git, command

What is the use of Git? What are the basic commands in it? And what is push and pull commands? How do you initialize a new Git repository?
Explain the concepts of repository, commit, branch, and merge.
Please explain what to do in it because I am really curious about it.

I just installed Git and not able to understand what to do in it.

Comment: Question is a lot too broad, needs focus.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of Git Basic Commands in pushing the created project

- 'git init'  - Initializes a new Git repository in your current directory.
- 'git add .' - Adds a file to the staging area (preparing it for a commit).
- 'git commit -m "Your message here"' - Records and save changes to the repository with a descriptive message.

Now, you are able to connect that remote repository with your local one. To do this, use the command:

-- $ git remote add origin 'INSERT REMOTE REPOSITORY URL HERE'

You’re almost done! Now, we’ll push the changes from the local repository to the new remote one. Use this command to do so:

-- $ git push origin main

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed version control system, ie a system which can track changes and manage your code or documents or any artifacts. Distributed means you can have a local copy of the repository (this happens when you clone the project) and then make your changes and save the changes locally without the server knowing anything about it. So basically consider a scenario of a team working on a product development. The team would have multiple developers, each of them can develop their piece locally. It allows for setting up better code workflow for eg: reviews etc. before the code is pushed to the servers, due to the distributed nature. These are few of the advantages of git. The basic commands as suggested in the above answer are good enough to start with GIT.